# Flot: cumulative data in same bar

Tags: jquery, time, flot, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a Flot bar chart with time on the x axis. The problem is that I'd like to have the option for users to show the bars in days or in months. When i use `tickSize: [1, "month"]` all data that fall in the range of the day is displayed through each other.

How can I sum op this data without changing the input data?

Comment: I have no idea about flot... but you can use [c3 Charts](http://c3js.org/) if u want to update data in charts as u like.... if u have the data

Comment: Look at the stacking plugin: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/stacking/index.html

Comment: @Mark The problem is that the stacking plugin requires the data to be sorted on x. That's the thing i wanted to achieve.